# How to label value of unchecked checkboxes with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have multiple checkboxes with label, i want to get label of unchecked checkboxes and send these label values to php file when form is submitted.
I'm doing this but didn't work

```js
$('.checkbox_0').click(function() {
  $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    $(this).next('label').text()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="firstCheckbox" name="firstCheckbox" class="checked_0">
<label for="firstCheckbox">Attendance to shifts are regular and no last minute shift cancellation</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="secondCheckbox" name="secondCheckbox" class="checked_0">
<label for="secondCheckbox">Attendance to shifts are regular and no last minute shift cancellation</label>
```

Comment: Please share your html code.

Comment: question updated please check html code now

Comment: there is no class name exists in your code with "checkbox_0". From where you'll get it?

Comment: And your function doesn't do anything.

Comment: @RajuAhmed please check again

Comment: @schmauch console.log($(".checkbox_0[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)").nextAll('label').text());
this is works for me but it gives me all labels in one paragraph i want to get label seprately and store it in array.

Comment: Why would you want to send the contents of the `<label>` element? `<input>`s have a `value` attribute you can use to set values to send

Comment: @RajuAhmed i'm getting desirable result but having issue in one thing that the labels i'm getting like this
0 => Attendance to visit were\n                                                    punctual and regularly met punctuality compliance
1 => On each visit, duration\n                                                    of visit completed in line with compliance
i need no space

Comment: @ZaInUlAbiDeenSān, You can share your problem in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). And provide us the link so that we can help you.

Comment: "but didn't work" - what does that mean? What do you want to achieve? What exactly is not working yet? And how is this problem related to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the uncheck label in a separate array as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var unCheckedLabelText=[];
  $('.checkboxClass').click(function () {
     unCheckedLabelText=[];
        $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function(){
            var text=$(this).next('label').text();
            unCheckedLabelText.push(text);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the right class selector and push it into an array.

How to send it to PHP depends on your implementation.

```js
$('.checked_0').click(function() {
  let result = [];
  $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    result.push($(this).next('label').text());
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="firstCheckbox" name="firstCheckbox" class="checked_0">
<label for="firstCheckbox">Attendance to shifts are regular and no last minute shift cancellation</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="secondCheckbox" name="secondCheckbox" class="checked_0">
<label for="secondCheckbox">Attendance to shifts are regular and no last minute shift cancellation</label>
```